# How do I implement .NET Core Health Checks on a Hosted Service?

Tags: .net-core, kubernetes-health-check

The question is just as asked on the title. It is simple to perform a check for the database operations, queries, commands and event store but I am clueless as to how/what is the best way to perform a health check on a hostedservice. Could anyone advice?

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1) answer your question ? You need to configure specific endpoint in your application which then can be used for performing healthcheck probes by kubernetes.

Comment: @mario Nope! haha, i wish it was tho, I specifically want a HostedService to be checked for its health, i.e. its memory usage (if possible) or at least whether if it is still functioning properly or not.

Comment: @ Nicholas, so unfortunatelly I won't be able to help you this time. ;) I couldn't find anything about performing health checks specifically on a hosted service either. Good luck!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Additionally from Simon B, this [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1) has drafted out a complete guide to writing a health check structure for your Hosted services.

You need 3 elements:

1. The HealthCheck class for your hosted service
2. The HealthCheck Provider DI, along with the HealthCheck class' DI.
3. A HealthCheck publisher

Answer (score 9):

The `IHostedService` interface (and `BackgroundService` base implementation) has overridable methods `StartAsync()` and `StopAsync()`.
In our background service we have:

```
public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
      _logger.LogWarning("Background service stopping");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

You could use this to run whatever you want to notify in some way when your `HostedService` starts or stops.

If you need to have a way of polling the service, you could perhaps inject a singleton that has a simple status within it, that is set by these methods. Then, a health check controller on your API / website could also have that injected and read the status of the singleton. Something like this:

```
    public interface IHostedServiceStatus
    {
        bool IsHostedServiceRunning { get; set; }
    }

    public class HostedServiceStatus : IHostedServiceStatus
    {
        public bool IsHostedServiceRunning { get; set; }
    }
```

Set that up as a singleton, inject into your `HostedService` and set `IsHostedServiceRunning` on the `StartAsync()` and `StopAsync()` methods appropriately.
Then also inject into your health check controller and read `IsHostedServiceRunning`.

Comment: Apologies simon, give me some time on this. Will follow ur guide and respond when i can!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [ExecuteTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.executetask?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) property of the [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the Task that executes the background operation.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Will return <see langword="null"/> if the background operation hasn't started.
/// </remarks>
public virtual Task? ExecuteTask => _executeTask;
```

Using this you can derive the status of the background service as follows:

```
@if (service.ExecuteTask == null)
{
    // Status = "Loading"
}
else
{
    if(!service.ExecuteTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        // Status = "Running"
    }
    else
    {
        // Status = "Stopped"
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could even use the task's [TaskStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=net-7.0)